Holomorphic 1-forms given coordinate patches on Riemann surface
If we are given a Riemann surface of genus at least 1 defined through coordinate patches and the relationships between the different coordinate patches, is there any algorithm to construct (some of) the holomorphic 1-forms on this surface by hand?
This means we do not, initially, have a description of the surface as an algebraic curve. (For example, given an algebraic curve $w^2 = \prod_{n=1}^6 (z-a_n)$, the holomorphic 1-forms are known. This is not the case here.)
Furthermore, assume the transformations linking different coordinate patches are not (all) Möbius transformations. (If they are, one can massage it into a Schottky representation, and I have found the solution there. It’s infinite products of rational functions.) The transformation functions have branch cuts away from the regions of overlap.
I found some papers in this direction, usually computing the period matrix, but all numeric. I’m searching for something analytic, by hand.
The plumbing construction does help if the genus is at least 2, as you can cut some handles, solve the problem in lower genus, and then do perturbation in the inverse length of the handle that was cut. But it seems to me you should solve the problem for genus 1 before you can start plumbing. And I can’t even do that.
Who can help me?
EDIT: What I mean is like in this paper, eq. (3.12): an actual formula. But that paper is for Schottky representation; I need something more general.

No, there is not. A priori, you do not even know that nonzero forms exist.

Why not? Doesn’t any genus $g$ Riemann surface have a $g$-dimensional vector space of holomorphic 1-forms?

Of course it does. But there is no easy proof of this. In particular, afaik, there is no "gluing" proof.

I’m not asking for an easy proof or a gluing proof; existence has been proven and I don’t care how difficult it was. I’m asking for a construction. The $g$-dimensional vector space of holomorphic 1-forms is known to exist. I want to explicitly compute at least one element of it.

You can do this, for instance if your surface is given as a ramified covering over sphere. But if all what you knowvare coordinate patches, then an explicit construction would lead no an easy proof of nonvanishing.

Sorry, but I really don’t understand what your problem is. If I construct a nonzero 1-form, then that is indeed a proof that a nonzero 1-form exists. But we know that nonzero 1-forms exist! Infinitely many of them! It’s Riemann surface of genus $g>0$! And if an “easy” proof is somehow disallowed (I really wouldn’t see why), then it’s enough if the explicit construction is difficult. I’m happy with difficult.

My problem is that I do not understand the meaning of the words "explicit" or "algorithm" in this context.  If you just want to understand the existence theorem without going through the full Riemann-Roch theorem, here is how you can do it: (1) Prove the de Rham theorem. (2) Prove the Hodge theorem (representing de Rham classes of closed differential forms via harmonic forms)- this is the hard part. (3) Convert a nonzero harmonic form (Poincare dual to some nonzero homology class) to a nonzero holomorphic form using the Hodge star. Is it "explicit enough"? I do not know.

No, I don’t want to understand the existence theorem. Where did you get that? I don’t want to prove anything. I’m happy with the proofs people came up with. I want to compute. Given coordinate transformations, I want to compute a 1-form in one of the coordinate patches. The meaning of the words “explicit” or “algorithm” in this context is the same as in any other context.
